# How to check for existence of variable inside string definition of other variable?

Tags: php, isset

I am curious to know whether there is a way in PHP to check for the existence of a variable inside the string definition of another variable. This is what I like to achieve:

```
$foobar = 'I ate '.isset($bananas) ? $bananas : "zero".' bananas';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some parenthesis:

```
$foobar = 'I ate '.(isset($bananas) ? $bananas : "zero").' bananas';
```

As you're looking for «zero», you can also use `empty`:

```
$foobar = 'I ate '.(!empty($bananas) ? $bananas : 'zero').' bananas';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$foobar = 'I ate ' . ((isset($bananas)) ? $bananas : "zero") . ' bananas';
```

Yes there is just put the condition in a bracket

Answer (score 0):

```
 $foobar = 'I ate '.($bananas != '' ? $bananas : 'zero').' bananas';
```

you can check whatever you want.